# Using links in different folders for images (Java)

Tags: java, image, swing, hyperlink

I'm designing a calculator with customised buttons. Naturally I want to organise my image files in folders different to the package interfaces.
The location of the folders is interfaces/Seven/seven-normal.png but whenever I don't include the full link

```
    "C:\Liloka\Source\interfaces\Seven\seven-normal.png"
```

it doesn't work and everything disappears. I swear I have seen this being done in normal code.  If I used this in proper programs I can't expect people to be changing the link to where they've put the code! Here's the code I've been using:

```
    seven = new ButtonImage("/Seven/seven-normal.png"); - Doesn't work
    nine = new ButtonImage("C:/Users/Liloka/workspace/WebsiteContent/src/interfaces/Nine/nine-normal.png"); - Does work
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"/Seven/seven-normal.png"
```

...is a path to `C:\Seven\seven-normal.png` - because of the `/` at the very beginning of your path, which essentially means, `from the root of the drive, go to the "Seven" folder, and then load "seven-normal.png"`

You have to use a relative path, something like, `"../../interfaces/Seven/seven-normal.png"` or maybe just `"interfaces/Seven/seven-normal.png"`

The first path will take you "up" two folders, and then down to `interfaces/Seven/seven-normal.png`. Essentially, you have to figure out what folder your code is running under, also called the "working directory", and construct a relative path from there.

Comment: Ah right.. I thought that would mean go to interfaces\Seven as if the file looks for anything such as another class as long as it's in interfaces that to me is the first place it would look for anything; but obviously not. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the first forward slash.

```
seven = new ButtonImage("interfaces/Seven/seven-normal.png");
```

`interfaces` is the folder that should be in the same folder as your JAR.